# Is it possible to generate services for Angular2 from Loopback?

Tags: javascript, angular, loopbackjs, angular-loopback

Here is documentation about [AngularJS JavaScript SDK](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/AngularJS+JavaScript+SDK)

This example works perfect for Angular. It is possible to generate Angular client library with command

```
$ lb-ng ../server/server.js js/lb-services.js
```

Does exist same easy way to use Angular2 with Loopback?

**EDIT**

What I found on this theme currently.

1. [Issue](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-sdk-angular/issues/188) in loopback-sdk-angular Github repository with discussion.
2. Example of realisation: [BaseResource](https://github.com/cajoy/falloutlab.com/blob/master/client/scripts/models/BaseResource.ts) and [Model](https://github.com/cajoy/falloutlab.com/blob/master/client/scripts/models/PerkModel.ts) mased on BaseResource.
3. And another way - using [upgrade](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html) from Angular to Angular2 until the official implemntation of Loopback Angular 2 SDK.
4. I have done alpha version of code generator for Angular 2 [in fork of loopback-sdk-angular](https://github.com/Qeti/loopback-sdk-angular).

**EDIT**

5. [Loopback-sdk-builder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/loopback-sdk-builder)
   ([comment](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-sdk-angular/issues/188#issuecomment-227147043))

Answer (score 14, accepted):

At this moment you may use fork of loopback-sdk-angular and loopback-sdk-angular-cli packages.

package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
  //...
  "loopback-sdk-angular": "github:qeti/loopback-sdk-angular#188-angular2-support",
  "loopback-sdk-angular-cli": "github:qeti/loopback-sdk-angular-cli#37-angular2-support"
}
```

Generate client code (TypeScript):

```
./node_modules/.bin/lb-ng ./server/server.js ./client/src/app/lb-services.ts -l angular2
```

Example of usage:

```
import {Component,Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {UserApi as UserService} from './lb-services';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [UserService,HTTP_PROVIDERS],
  template: 'some template'
})

@Injectable()
export class AppComponent {

  private login: string;
  private password: string;

  constructor(protected user: UserService) {}

  onLogin() {
    let self = this;
    // Example 1
    this.user.login({
      username: self.login,
      password: self.password
    })
    .subscribe(res => {
      // some actions on login
      this.getData();
    });
  }

  onLogout() {
    // Example 2
    this.user.logout().subscribe(() => {
      // some actions on logout
    });
  }

  public getData() {
    // Example 3
    this.user.count().subscribe((response: any) => {
      let lastRow = response.count;

      let data = this.user
        // Example 4
        .find({
          offset: 0,
          limit: 100
        })
        .subscribe(function(response: any) {
          // Process response
        });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I am getting the following exception `EXCEPTION: No provider for Http! (App -> UserApi -> Http)` thoughts?

Comment: @essaji, show your code please. How you provide Http into your component? Are there `providers: [Http]`?. You can create an issue (https://github.com/Qeti/loopback-sdk-angular/issues) with code example.

Comment: Using `providers: [UserService,Http],` produces `EXCEPTION: No provider for ConnectionBackend! (AppComponent -> UserApi -> Http -> ConnectionBackend)` and using `providers: [UserService,Http,ConnectionBackend],` produces `EXCEPTION: No provider for RequestOptions! (AppComponent -> UserApi -> Http -> RequestOptions)`

Comment: And using `providers: [UserService,Http,ConnectionBackend,RequestOptions],` produces `EXCEPTION: Cannot resolve all parameters for 'RequestOptions'(?). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'RequestOptions' is decorated with Injectable.`

Comment: Here is the link to [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/mebNcuund9zWYtUOWWE9?p=preview) see console for the error messages.

Comment: Try to provide also `HTTP_PROVIDERS`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106098/discussion-between-essaji-and-mnv).

Comment: Did you use `Codegen` for generating Angular2 typescript SDK?

Comment: @essaji I use loopback-sdk-angular package

Comment: Would you mind sharing the server.js file of the above application? I'm trying to implement a similar application with a loopback API and Angular 2 frontend and having a difficulty in integrating them. Thanks!

Comment: @imesh Did you try https://github.com/mean-expert-official/loopback-sdk-builder ?